# How to display sql query results on table with html select option?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new with PHP and I want to make a form which will query a database. I created a database in PHPmyadmin and I want to show the results on a table when a user selects an option on a dropdown menu.

Let's say for an example that I want to see which task is complete on a table. I click on the dropdown menu and select "Fait" (For done. Sorry, I'm French). After that, it will query the DB which will display all the information with the value "Fait" (done)  on that column. I managed to get all the data displayed on my table but, I want to have an option to filter the results.

I searched online but only found for the most case result displayed on the dropdown menu, which is not what I'm looking for.

I want to be able to do my research with PHP if possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Formulaire</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formulaire.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="select.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="form">

<form>

<label>Veuillez choisir une option :</label>
<select id="choix">
  <option value="Tous">Tous</option>
  <option value="À faire">À faire</option>
  <option value="fait">fait</option>
 </select>
    
 <table id="tableau">
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "company");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM login";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["username"] . "</td><td>"
    . $row["password"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } else { echo "0 results"; }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
    </table>

<textarea id="description"rows="10" cols="162" placeholder="Décrivez le problème."></textarea>
    
    <div id="soumettre"> 
    &nbsp;&nbsp; Choisir un fichier à envoyer:<div></div>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" multiple>
    <div></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Effacer" name="reset" />
    </div>
    

</form action="mailto:xyz@xyz.com" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

</div>

<script>


function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function fnselect(){
    
    alert($("tr.selected td:first" ).html());
}

</script>
<p>
sdasd</p>

</body>

</html>
```

I dug on the web and found some code that I changed some bits. I was able to make it worked! The only thing I need to find out is when I click on the button, to refresh the page and show the data. For now, it only work once. I have to reload the page manually to make another research. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Formulaire</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formulaire.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="select.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="form">

<form action="#" method="post">

<label>Veuillez choisir une option :</label>
<select id="choix" name="choixtest">
  <option value="id">id</option>
  <option value="username">username</option>
  <option value="password">password</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
    
    
 <table id="tableau">
    
    
    <?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "company");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>id</th>";
                echo "<th>username</th>";
                echo "<th>password</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $selected_val = $_POST['choixtest'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable

           
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[$selected_val] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td>"  . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
            

        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>

    </table>


</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```